# Laravel Cashier throwing exception No such subscription on cancel subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

## "No such subscription: 'sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN' ".

I am trying to cancel a stripe subscription using Laravel cashier. Upon
calling the `cancelNow()` function Stripe throws an exception. Every time I send a different Stripe plan but Stripe throws the same exception:

> No such subscription: 'sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN'

```
if ($user->subscription('main',$subscription->stripe_plan)->cancelNow()) {
    session()->flash('error', 'Unsubscribed package succesfully.');
}
```

Comment: Are you using Connect?  If so, is it possible the Subscription exists on a different account?  Another possibility is that you're using the wrong API key somewhere.

Comment: Here is the scenerio: 1) i have created three plans . 2) I have subscribed all these plans .3) i unsubscribed first plan , it unsubscribed succefully . 4) when i unsubscribe 2nd plan , stripe/laravel cashier throw this exception "No such subscription: 'sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN'"

Comment: sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN  this is id of the 1st subscription which unsubscribed/canceled . i don't know why stripe throwing this id sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN upon 2nd time when i unsubscribe

Comment: Can you share the code you're using unsubscribe the first plan?  It sounds like you might be canceling the entire Subscription rather than removing one plan.

Comment: ` foreach($user->subscriptions as $subscription)            
        if($subscription->stripe_status != 'canceled' && $subscription->stripe_plan == $package['stripe_plan_id'] ){   
            $subscriptionId = $subscription->stripe_plan;
         }
        }
        try{

            if( $user->subscription($subscriptionId)->cancelNow())
                {
                    session()->flash('error', 'Unsubscribed package succesfully.');
                }   
            }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        session()->flash('error', 'Something went wrong.');
    } `

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue: you're trying to cancel the Subscription after the `foreach` loop instead of inside it.  The `foreach` loop goes through all the Subscriptions the user has and sets `$subscriptionId` if the conditions match, but doesn't do anything else.  So if a user has three matching subscriptions `$subscriptionId` will be set to the first, then the second, then the third, and *then* the `try/catch` blocks will run.  I think you need to move the `try/catch` blocks inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I should also point out that the PHP code you provided in your comment above doesn't actually work due to syntax errors; you should edit your original question and add the code there so it's properly formatted and does not have syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

This error shows that there is no subscription with the id provided. Maybe you have to check the environment of Stripe you use. There are different data based on the env you are, so you have to check if the data exist on your env.

In stripe there are two different envs: production and test

Comment: Here is the scenario: 1) i have created three plans . 2) I have subscribed all these plans .3) i unsubscribed first plan , it unsubscribed successfully . 4) when i unsubscribe 2nd plan , stripe/laravel cashier throw this exception "No such subscription: 'sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN'"

Comment: sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN  this is id of the 1st subscription which unsubscribed/canceled . i don't know why stripe throwing this id sub_Ic51hhLuYFOFNN upon 2nd time when i unsubscribe

Comment: You cannot unsubscribe again the same subscription I guess. Maybe this is the problem. You have to check if you have setup stripe correctly based on the logic of your app

Comment: yes, i cannot unsubscribe the same subscription & iam not trying to do it. the problem is that iam passing different stripe_plan key every time but stripe throw same exception all the time i click unsubscribe

Comment: Does the Stripe plan key exist for the specified subscription?

Comment: As I can see from your comment above, I think that there is problem with your code. If you want to cancel all the subs, you have to loop and then cancel every sub inside the loop. This way is better I guess.